Calculating curl in cylindrical and cartesian coordinates
So I have this vector function $\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{i}r\cos\omega t + \mathbf{j} r\sin\omega t$, where $x=r\cos\omega t$ and $y=r\sin\omega t$.
I want to find the curl of it's time derivative, $\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}=\mathbf{v}=\omega (-\mathbf{i}y+\mathbf{j}x)$. I want to do this in both cartesian and cylindrical coordinates. Since the curl is along the $z$ axis, I expected both answers to be the same. However, I think I made some mistake.

Here is what I did:
Cartesian:
$\nabla \times \mathbf{v}=\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \\
-\omega y & \omega x & 0  \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=\mathbf{i}\cdot 0+ \mathbf{j}\cdot0+\mathbf{k}\cdot (\omega-[-\omega])=2\mathbf{k}\omega$

Cylindrical:
Coordinates: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \Rightarrow r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{r^2(\sin^2\omega t + \cos^2\omega t)}=r$ and $\frac{y}{x}=\tan{\theta} \Rightarrow \theta=\arctan\frac{y}{x}$. But in the case of $\mathbf{v}$, the x-coordinate is $-y$ and the y-coordinate is $x$. So for $\mathbf{v}$, we get: $\theta=\arctan(\frac{r \cos \omega t}{-r\sin\omega t})=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(\omega t)}\right)$. This looks somewhat nasty.
Ok, so if we do take $\mathbf{R}$ in cylindical coordinates instead, we get $r=r$ and $\theta=\arctan(\tan(\omega t))=\omega t$, which is much easier to work with.
Taking $\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}$ we note that $r$ is not a function of time, and thus we get $\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}t}=\mathbf{r}r+\mathbf{\theta}\omega$. Alternativley, we can do $\nabla \times \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{R}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( \nabla\times \mathbf{R}\right)$.
The curl in cylindrical coordinates is:
$$(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})_r=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial F_\theta}{\partial z}$$
$$(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})_\theta=\frac{\partial F_r}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial r}$$
$$(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})_z=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(rF_\theta)-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F_r}{\partial \theta}$$
In this case, $v_z=0$ and $r$ and $\theta$ doesn't change in the $z$ direction, so all terms with $F_z$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ vanish.
$$\Rightarrow \left( \nabla\times \mathbf{R}\right)=\left( \nabla\times \mathbf{R}\right)_z=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\cdot \omega t)-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\omega t}{r}-0$$
I used that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta}=0$ because the length $r$ doesn't change even though the unit vector $\mathbf{r}$ changes direction. (When varying the angle, the value of the radius stays constant).
If we take the time derivative we get:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( \nabla\times \mathbf{R}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( \frac{\omega t}{r}\mathbf{k} \right)=\mathbf{k}\frac{\omega}{r}\neq 2\mathbf{k}\omega$$


Where did I go wrong? Was my assumption that $\nabla \times \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{R}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left( \nabla\times \mathbf{R}\right)$ wrong? I feel like that one should hold true since $x,y$ and $z$ are continous, differentiable functions in both $t$ and coordinates. Or can't I convert $\mathbf{R}$ to cylindrical and then take the derivative? Or did I make some other math mistake?
I feel like the answers should be the same?

As to avoid problems, I'd define
$$\mathbf R=r\cos\theta\,\mathbf i+r\sin\theta\, \mathbf j=r\mathbf{\hat r}\ \ \text{ with }\ \ r\neq r(t)\text{ and }\theta=\theta(t)$$
and after having differentiated wrt $t$ and taken the curl or viceversa, I'd do $\theta=\omega t$.
Let's first do the case $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\nabla\times\mathbf R)$; we'll do the other one later to corroborate that they're not the same. Let's start by computing the curl:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf R=\frac{1}{r}
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{\hat r} & r\boldsymbol{\hat \theta} & \mathbf{\hat z}\\
\partial_r & \partial_\theta & \partial_z\\
r & 0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=0$$
Notice how it yields $0$ because $\mathbf R$ is a central field and thus a conservative field (their curl is $0$). The temporal derivative will still be $0$ which insinuates
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\nabla\times\mathbf R)\neq \nabla\times\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf R}{\mathrm dt}$$
As for the other case, let's start by computing the temporal derivative:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf R}{\mathrm dt}=r\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf{\hat r}}{\mathrm dt}=r\dot\theta\boldsymbol{\hat \theta}$$
Now we can apply the curl:
$$\nabla\times\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf R}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{1}{r}
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{\hat r} & r\boldsymbol{\hat \theta} & \mathbf{\hat z}\\
\partial_r & \partial_\theta & \partial_z\\
0 & r\cdot r\dot\theta & 0
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(r^2\dot\theta)}{\partial r}\mathbf{\hat z}=2\dot\theta\mathbf{\hat z}$$
Substituting $\theta=\omega t$, we get
$$\nabla\times\dfrac{\mathrm d \mathbf R}{\mathrm dt}=2\omega\mathbf{\hat z}$$
The main problem here was that the time derivative of a unit vector with constant modulus changes its direction perpendicular to the original unit vector which means the curl isn't the same for each of them.

Why is the angular component of R zero? Otherwise I can follow what you did. Thank you!

Also, I wonder if you in general can't pull the time derivative out of the curl? Is there any cases when you can?

Well, if you factor $r$ you'll get $\cos\theta \mathbf i+\sin\theta\mathbf j$ which is by definition the radial unit vector.

Ok, thanks! @Conreu

As for pulling the time derivative out of the curl, it is done in electromagnetism to deduce the wave equation for the electric and magnetic field, though it is a partial derivative with time, not a total one.
